# Invalid root node configured for pages. - Sitefinity on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sitefinity-8

I am trying to restore an old site with Sitefinity version 8.
I have restored the database to my local machine and the local copy is running just fine. But when trying to put publish it to Azure it fails.

I get the following error:

> Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of
>   "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002".

I used the MS SQL Server Management studio to export the data to Azure. It has indeed transferred and all the data appears to be there.

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydatabase;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" dbType="SqlAzure" name="Sitefinity" />
```

I also tried using myuser@mydatabase for the user id, but was getting an error saying it could not connect to the server.

I have been reading up on why other people had the same problem but could only find instances where the database default schema was not set. This is not something one can set on azure as far as I know.
Also I did actually run this same app on azure before and it worked just fine. My connection string is based on my old version. 
I am either forgetting something to do to get it to run or things on azure have changed and now it needs to be done differently.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also copied the config files from the App_Data / Sitefinity / Configuration folder to Azure?

Particularly, the ProjectConfig.config has a **siteMapRootNodeId** attribute which must match the Ids in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I only had one file from that folder included, the DataConfig.config file.
I have now added the whole folder. Unfortunately that just gives me different errors. I now get an empty page on arrival. and when trying to login get the following error:
Missing configuration for the requesting relying party "https:/mysite.com"

Comment: That indicates a problem with the SecurityConfig settings. Can you confirm you restored the database that works fine on your local and copied all config files?

Comment: Yes, I copied the whole config folder and restored the data from my local version. Using the export data task in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: You can check this article for the latest error: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/missing-configuration-for-the-requesting-relying-party

Comment: I have tried this already, it did not make any difference, the error is the same.